# Backspace key interrupting on Ajax call in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, browser

I am working on E-commerce site with cart module. In that have qty box to update the qty. qty trigger key-up jQuery event with $.ajax method. as soos as trigger key-up event i am disabling the qty box and sending the request to server.

Issue is . In between if user press backspace key from key board browser navigating to previous page . Please help me how to prevent backspace .

Thanks.

Comment: That's quite pointless because anyway user can still click on browser back button. Maybe i misunderstood your issue though

Comment: Not sure to get the issue either... Do you want to prevent user from leaving the page or do you want to ensure the AJAX is sent even if the user left?

Comment: @kaiido , I want to prevnt the user from leaving the page untill i get the response from ajax.

Comment: ...wrong answer... Why do you want to do this? (There is a way to send data to server, even if the page unloads)

Comment: Hi @kaiido, I am not aware of this. can you please tell me how to end data to server, even if the page unloads.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code key-up event.

```
   if(! $(event.target).is('input')) {
        console.log(event.which);
       //event.preventDefault();
       if(event.which == 8) {
        //  alert('backspace pressed');
        return false;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Harsh ,This issue is occurring in Firefox  browser.  I have tried your code its not working

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want is actually to ensure the data has been sent to server even if the user leaves the page, you can try to use the [Navigator#sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) method, which is made for exactly this case.

This method will allow you to send a small amount of data asynchronously, even after the page unloaded.

Unfortunately, it is still not widely supported (no IE nor Safari), so you will have to have a mixed behavior, e.g

```
if(typeof window.navigator === 'object' &&
  typeof navigator.sendBeacon === 'function') {
    navigator.sendBeacon(yourData);
  }
else{
    $.ajax(...
  }
```